# catch cancel click nsis installer from shellexecuteex

Tags: c++, nsis

Hi I am trying to run my installer using the ShellExecuteEx from a c++ application. I am able to make my installer run. If i click cancel on my NSIS installer anytime how do I catch that from C++ application and print installation failed.

I tried like this

```
if((UINT)ShExecInfo.hInstApp <= SE_ERR_DDETIMEOUT ) 
{
    fprintf(fp, "Failed to start the installer \n");
    exit(-1);   
}
```

But no luck, I tried to print whats in `ShExecInfo.hInstApp` and the result is number 42. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hInstApp` holds which error (if any) occurred during start up. It has nothing to do with the application closing.

You want to look at the exit code of the installer process with `GetExitCodeProcess`, which is stored in `ShExecInfo.hProcess` if you set the `SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS` flag in `ShExecInfo.fMask`.

You'll have to check the NSIS documentation for the exit code returned when the user hits cancel.